# mysql issue : After upgrading to Mac OS X 11.6 on Apple Silicon M1 mini, cannot connect

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

Mysql was working fine on my M1 Mac Mini yesterday until I installed the 11.6 update.   After installing, I'm getting hammered with connection issues.

Mac OS X 11.6
Mac mini (M1, 2020)
mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for macos11.6 on arm64 (Homebrew

Seeing this a great deal - maybe 3 out of 4 times I try to connect  :

```
~  mysql -u root -p                           
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

mysqld is running, and I can sometimes get a connection for long enough to bring up the mysql client, but as soon as I type a query, I lose connection.

```
~  mysql -u root -p                           
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.27 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use history;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server
```

Any ideas?   I've tried upgrading mysql and mysql-client, I've tried removing and reinstalling mysql in homebrew, I've played around with my.cnf settings, none of those seem to help.